# Can I use plain HTML to write views in the Express framework?

Tags: html, templates, node.js, express, pug

So I started to use node.js along with the Express framework, but I dont know how to get rid of Jade and all the other templates... I want to write my views in plain HTML. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use plain HTML, you don't need to use views at all -- just serve the HTML pages as static files. If you want to be able to use your node.js variables, or include files within files, then you'll have to have *some* kind of templating language.

Comment: Thanks! And can I use a different templating language, for example Eco?

Comment: You can use whatever template language you like, but you might have to provide the integration code yourself :)

Comment: I was in the same spot and ended up switching to mustache.js templating which gives you django/smarty type js templates.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe others have come across this page as I did and are looking for a good solution that lets you write typical raw HTML as your template, and maybe even lets you add variables into your HTML like `<b><% = myvariable %></b>` that they can send in from their Node.js javascript. Or they could just use plain raw HTML.

The solution is EJS.

You can do it this way:

1. Install ejs in the root directory of your Node.js project:

   ```
   npm install ejs --save
   ```

   (`--save` also saves ejs to your `package.json` file if it exists)
2. Set your template engine in app.js as ejs

   ```
   // app.js
   app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
   app.set('view engine', 'html');
   ```
3. Now in your route file you can assign template variables

   ```
   // ./routes/index.js
   exports.index = function(req, res){
   res.render('index', { title: 'ejs' });};
   ```
4. Then you can create your html view in /views directory.

Here's a full step by step walk through of the process of getting EJS and Express working: http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/31/how-to-use-ejs-in-express/

See http://www.embeddedjs.com/ for more information, and of course you can Google "ejs express" no quotes.